# R: ggplot customize transform axis label to reduce zeros

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my following code:

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(scales)
myData <- data.frame(
  platform = c("Windows", "MacOs", "Linux"),
  number = c(27000, 16000, 9000)
)

ggplot(myData, aes(x = reorder(platform, -number), y = number))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="darkturquoise", width = 0.5)+
  geom_text(aes(label = number), vjust=-0.3)+
  xlab("Platform")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(0,40000, by = 5000), 1))
```

that produces this plot:
[image]

How do I change the param of `scale_y_continuous` to reduce the number of `000`? i.e, the y-tick will show 5, 10, 15, 20, 25...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the y-axis' labels by 1000 like so:

```
ggplot(myData, aes(x = reorder(platform, -number), y = number))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="darkturquoise", width = 0.5)+
  geom_text(aes(label = number), vjust=-0.3)+
  xlab("Platform")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq( 0,40000, by = 5000),
                     labels = function(y_value) y_value / 1000)  # <- ! here !
```